# Why am I getting an error when sending an email through a React EmailJS form?

Tags: reactjs

I have just added a contact form to my website using EmailJS but I'm getting an error whenever I try to send an email. It's linked to my email but I'm not sure what the issue is. If I knew what the error meant then I could figure out how to fix it.

I've logged the error in the console :  bundle.js:1667
POST https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send-form 400

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?
Please comment if you need any more info
Thanks!

Comment: Open network tab and read the payload message

Comment: Hi Konrad, there's no message there?